# automating the login to the uk data service website in R with RCurl or httr

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping, rcurl, httr

I am in the process of writing a collection of freely-downloadable R scripts for http://asdfree.com/ to help people analyze the complex sample survey data hosted by the [UK data service](http://ukdataservice.ac.uk/). In addition to providing lots of statistics tutorials for these data sets, I also want to automate the download and importation of this survey data. In order to do that, I need to figure out how to programmatically log into this [UK data service website](https://www.esds.ac.uk/secure/UKDSRegister_start.asp).

I have tried lots of different configurations of **RCurl** and **httr** to log in, but I'm making a mistake somewhere and I'm stuck. I have tried inspecting the elements [as outlined in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213194/use-rcurl-to-bypass-disclaimer-page-then-do-the-web-scrapping/10214010#10214010), but the websites jump around too fast in the browser for me to understand what's going on.

This website does require a login and password, but I believe I'm making a mistake before I even get to the login page.

### Here's how the website works:

The starting page should be: https://www.esds.ac.uk/secure/UKDSRegister_start.asp

This page will automatically re-direct your web browser to a long URL that starts with: `https://wayf.ukfederation.org.uk/DS002/uk.ds?[blahblahblah]`

(1) For some reason, the SSL certificate does not work on this website. Here's [the SO question I posted regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411313/ssl-verification-causes-rcurl-and-httr-to-break-on-a-website-that-should-be-le). The workaround I've used is simply ignoring the SSL:

```
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

and then my first command on the starting website is:

```
z <- GET( "https://www.esds.ac.uk/secure/UKDSRegister_start.asp" )
```

this gives me back a `z$url` that looks a lot like the `https://wayf.ukfederation.org.uk/DS002/uk.ds?[blahblahblah]` page that my browser also re-directs to.

In the browser, then, you're supposed to type in "uk data archive" and click the `continue` button. When I do that, it re-directs me to the web page https://shib.data-archive.ac.uk/idp/Authn/UserPassword

I think this is where I'm stuck because I cannot figure out how to have cURL `followlocation` and land on this website. Note: no username/password has been entered yet.

When I use the **httr** `GET` command from the wayf.ukfederation.org.uk page like this:

```
 y <- GET( z$url , query = list( combobox = "https://shib.data-archive.ac.uk/shibboleth-idp" ) )
```

the `y$url` string looks a lot like `z$url` (except it's got a combobox= on the end). Is there any way to get through to this `uk data archive` authentication page with **RCurl** or **httr**?

I can't tell if I'm just overlooking something or if I absolutely must use the SSL certificate described in [my previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411313/ssl-verification-causes-rcurl-and-httr-to-break-on-a-website-that-should-be-le) or what?

(2) At the point I do make it through to that page, I believe the remainder of the code would just be:

```
values <- list( j_username = "your.username" , 
                j_password = "your.password" )
POST( "https://shib.data-archive.ac.uk/idp/Authn/UserPassword" , body = values)
```

But I guess that page will have to wait...

Answer (score 2):

The relevant data variables returned by the form are `action` and `origin`, not `combobox`. Give `action` the value `selection` and `origin` the value from the relevant entry in `combobox`

```
y <- GET( z$url, query = list( action="selection", origin = "https://shib.data-archive.ac.uk/shibboleth-idp") )
> y$url
[1] "https://shib.data-archive.ac.uk:443/idp/Authn/UserPassword"
```

**Edit**

It looks as though the handle pool isn't keeping your session alive correctly. You therefore need to pass the handles directly rather than automatically. Also for the `POST` command you need to set `multipart=FALSE` as this is the [default for HTML forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). The R command has a different default as it is mainly designed for uploading files. So:

```
y <- GET( handle=z$handle, query = list( action="selection", origin = "https://shib.data-archive.ac.uk/shibboleth-idp") )
POST(body=values,multipart=FALSE,handle=y$handle)
Response [https://www.esds.ac.uk/]
  Status: 200
  Content-type: text/html

...snipped...    


                <title>

                        Introduction to ESDS

                </title>

                <meta name="description" content="Introduction to the ESDS, home page" />
```

Comment: thanks! that gets me closer but doesn't finish the job..at the point you've made it through to that, i hit a similar roadblock with `POST( y$url , body = values)` where `values` is the list object specified in my question  ..any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, try using `multipart=FALSE`?

Comment: nope..instead of returning the same page, adding multipart=F causes it to break entirely :(  `An error occurred while processing your request.`

Comment: That might be "random" server issue as I don't get that by using `multipart=F`

Comment: ..i'm getting it consistently.  i'm using windows + r x64 3.0.1?  do you think the line `https://safari.data-archive.ac.uk/Shibboleth.sso/SAML/POST` ever needs to get used?  any other ideas? :/

Comment: i genuinely appreciate that you're continuing to work through this with me..and i apologize if i'm raising the bar here from what's posted, but it's not clear to me that this "Introduction to ESDS" page is actually logged-in? when i log in with a web browser, i get to a `Your account` page.  ..after all this, it should be able to download one of the files from `https://www.esds.ac.uk/newRegistration/UKDSshowProjectDataset.asp?pn=####` and i don't see this authentication holding to make it that far? :( logging in needs to allow downloading files and the path from this to that is unclear?

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Yes, the handle method seems to only pass the base of the url. Perhaps passing the cookies from the previous requests might work.

Comment: ..how? :/ sorry, i'm pretty lousy at webscraping.

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to address "enter your organization" page goes like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

org <- "your_organization"
user <- "your_username"
password <- "your_password"

signin <- "http://esds.ac.uk/newRegistration/newLogin.asp"
handle_reset(signin)

# get to org page and enter org
p0 <- html_session(signin) %>% 
    follow_link("Login")
org_link <- html_nodes(p0, "option") %>% 
    str_subset(org) %>% 
    str_match('(?<=\\")[^"]*') %>%
    as.character()

f0 <- html_form(p0) %>%
    first() %>%
    set_values(origin = org_link)
fake_submit_button <- list(name = "submit-btn",
                           type = "submit",
                           value = "Continue",
                           checked = NULL,
                           disabled = NULL,
                           readonly = NULL,
                           required = FALSE)
attr(fake_submit_button, "class") <- "btn-enabled"
f0[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- fake_submit_button

c0 <- cookies(p0)$value
names(c0) <- cookies(p0)$name
p1 <- submit_form(session = p0, form = f0, config = set_cookies(.cookies = c0))
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the whole problem—(2) is harder than it looks.  I've got more of what I think is a solution posted here: [R: use rvest (or httr) to log in to a site requiring cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701409/r-use-rvest-or-httr-to-log-in-to-a-site-requiring-cookies?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Hopefully someone will help us get the rest of the way.