# Using R to accept cookies to download a PDF file

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping, httr

I'm getting stuck on cookies when trying to download a PDF.

For example, if I have a [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.5284/1016790) for a PDF document on the Archaeology Data Service, it will resolve to [this landing page](http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archives/view/greylit/details.cfm?id=17755)
with an [embedded link in it to this pdf](http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/catalogue/adsdata/arch-822-1/dissemination/pdf/cambridg3-71577_1.pdf) but which really redirects to [this](http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archiveDS/archiveDownload?t=arch-822-1/dissemination/pdf/cambridg3-71577_1.pdf) other link.

`library(httr)` will handle resolving the DOI and we can extract the pdf URL from the landing page using `library(XML)` but I'm stuck at getting the PDF itself.

If I do this:

```
download.file("http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archiveDS/archiveDownload?t=arch-1352-1/dissemination/pdf/Dyfed/GL44004.pdf", destfile = "tmp.pdf")
```

then I receive a HTML file that is the same as http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/myads/

Trying the answer at [How to use R to download a zipped file from a SSL page that requires cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204503/how-to-use-r-to-download-a-zipped-file-from-a-ssl-page-that-requires-cookies) leads me to this:

```
library(httr)

terms <- "http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/myads/copyrights"
download <- "http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archiveDS/archiveDownload"
values <- list(agree = "yes", t = "arch-1352-1/dissemination/pdf/Dyfed/GL44004.pdf")

# Accept the terms on the form,
# generating the appropriate cookies

POST(terms, body = values)
GET(download, query = values)

# Actually download the file (this will take a while)

resp <- GET(download, query = values)

# write the content of the download to a binary file

writeBin(content(resp, "raw"), "c:/temp/thefile.zip")
```

But after the `POST` and `GET` functions I simply get the HTML of the same cookie page that I got with `download.file`:

```
> GET(download, query = values)
Response [http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/myads/copyrights?from=2f6172636869766544532f61726368697665446f776e6c6f61643f61677265653d79657326743d617263682d313335322d3125324664697373656d696e6174696f6e2532467064662532464479666564253246474c34343030342e706466]
  Date: 2016-01-06 00:35
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
  Size: 21 kB
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "h...
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; c...


            <title>Archaeology Data Service:  myADS</title>

            <link href="http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/css/u...
...
```

Looking at http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/about/Cookies it seems that the cookie situation at this site is complicated. Seems like this kind of cookie complexity is not unusual for UK data providers: [automating the login to the uk data service website in R with RCurl or httr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778543/automating-the-login-to-the-uk-data-service-website-in-r-with-rcurl-or-httr)

How can I use R to get past the cookies on this website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your plea on [rOpenSci](https://discuss.ropensci.org/t/getting-past-cookies-when-downloading-data-from-the-web/285) has been heard!

There's lots of javascript between those pages that makes it somewhat annoying to try to decipher via `httr` + `rvest`. Try `RSelenium`. This worked on OS X 10.11.2, R 3.2.3 & Firefox loaded.

```
library(RSelenium)

# check if a sever is present, if not, get a server
checkForServer()

# get the server going
startServer()

dir.create("~/justcreateddir")
setwd("~/justcreateddir")

# we need PDFs to download instead of display in-browser
prefs <- makeFirefoxProfile(list(
  `browser.download.folderList` = as.integer(2),
  `browser.download.dir` = getwd(),
  `pdfjs.disabled` = TRUE,
  `plugin.scan.plid.all` = FALSE,
  `plugin.scan.Acrobat` = "99.0",
  `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` = 'application/pdf'
))
# get a browser going
dr <- remoteDriver$new(extraCapabilities=prefs)
dr$open()

# go to the page with the PDF
dr$navigate("http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archives/view/greylit/details.cfm?id=17755")

# find the PDF link and "hit ENTER"
pdf_elem <- dr$findElement(using="css selector", "a.dlb3")
pdf_elem$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))

# find the ACCEPT button and "hit ENTER"
# that will save the PDF to the default downloads directory
accept_elem <- dr$findElement(using="css selector", "a[id$='agreeButton']")
accept_elem$sendKeysToElement(list("\uE007"))
```

Now wait for the download to complete. The R console will not be busy while  it downloads, so it is easy to close the session accidently, before the download has completed.

```
# close the session
dr$close()
```

Comment: Gave a try on Ubuntu 14.04, R 3.2.3 and Firefox. `dr$open()` reports
`[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Undefined error in RCurl call.Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts)) :`

Comment: This has always been my biggest nit to pick with Selenium in general (not necessarily the R pkg). Getting consistency between Windows, OS X & *nix is so difficult. Hopefully folks can add to this (all my *nix systems are very thinly configured headless server-y things and I'm not abt to try to master the phantomjs driver tonight :-)

Comment: OK, found how to make it to work on my computer. I had to manually start the selenium standalone server first with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.0.jar`. Then I can connect.

Comment: Thanks, rOpenSci to the rescue! That's a great workaround and gets it done. For improved portability it would be ideal to have the download in the R session's working directory, is that possible? I made some minor edits to add a little detail (worked for me on Win 7, R v3.2.3 with firefox).

Comment: Aye. I'll figure out the Firefox profile setting string and update the answer in a bit.

Comment: That took more effort than expected (initial profile settings weren't working, but the above did). You may need to quote the directory path better given the crazy Windows slashes, but I can confirm the above worked on 2 Macs.

Comment: I can confirm this works on my Ubuntu. Just had to skip the `checkForServer()` step, as keeping to try to download the standalone server, when a server is already running after `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.0.jar`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer came from [John Harrison](https://github.com/johndharrison) by email, posted here at his request:

This will allow you to download the PDF:

```
appURL <- "http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archiveDS/archiveDownload?t=arch-1352-1/dissemination/pdf/Dyfed/GL44004.pdf"
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiefile="cookies.txt"
           , curl=curl, followLocation = TRUE)
pdfData <- getBinaryURL(appURL, curl = curl, .opts = list(cookie = "ADSCOPYRIGHT=YES"))
writeBin(pdfData, "test2.pdf")
```

Here's a longer version showing his working

```
appURL <- "http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archiveDS/archiveDownload?t=arch-1352-1/dissemination/pdf/Dyfed/GL44004.pdf"
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiefile="cookies.txt"
           , curl=curl, followLocation = TRUE)
appData <- getURL(appURL, curl = curl)

# get the necessary elements for the POST that is initiated when the ACCEPT button is pressed

doc <- htmlParse(appData)
appAttrs <- doc["//input", fun = xmlAttrs]
postData <- lapply(appAttrs, function(x){data.frame(name = x[["name"]], value = x[["value"]]
                                                    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)})
postData <- do.call(rbind, postData)

# post your acceptance
postURL <- "http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/myads/copyrights.jsf;jsessionid="
# get jsessionid
jsessionid <- unlist(strsplit(getCurlInfo(curl)$cookielist[1], "\t"))[7]

searchData <- postForm(paste0(postURL, jsessionid), curl = curl,
                       "j_id10" = "j_id10",
                       from = postData[postData$name == "from", "value"],
                       "javax.faces.ViewState" = postData[postData$name == "javax.faces.ViewState", "value"],
                       "j_id10:_idcl" = "j_id10:agreeButton"
                       , binary = TRUE
)
con <- file("test.pdf", open = "wb")
writeBin(searchData, con)
close(con)


Pressing the ACCEPT button on the page you gave initiates a POST to "http://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/myads/copyrights.jsf;jsessionid=......" via some javascript.
This post then redirects to the page with the pdf having given some additional cookies.

Checking our cookies we see:

> getCurlInfo(curl)$cookielist
[1] "archaeologydataservice.ac.uk\tFALSE\t/\tFALSE\t0\tJSESSIONID\t3d249e3d7c98ec35998e69e15d3e" 
[2] "archaeologydataservice.ac.uk\tFALSE\t/\tFALSE\t0\tSSOSESSIONID\t3d249e3d7c98ec35998e69e15d3e"
[3] "archaeologydataservice.ac.uk\tFALSE\t/\tFALSE\t0\tADSCOPYRIGHT\tYES"          

so it would probably be sufficient to set that last cookie to start with (indicating we accept copyright)
```